# Submission form object is coming through as entire property key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pm2

My front-end guy is trying to got my login route to work, but when he sends through the request, the entire object is coming through as an object key:

```
3|app      | { '{"email":"james@oxido.co.uk","password":"test"}': '' }
```

It's supposed to come through as:

```
{'email': 'whatever', 'password': 'whatever'}
```

My route looks like this:

```
router.route('/login')
.post(async (req, res) => {

  console.log('########################')
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log('########################')

 # Authentication stuff

  }
});
```

His code looks like this:

```
  login(email, password){
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const uri = leadingURI + "adminapi/users/login"
    console.log(uri);
    request.open("POST", uri)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.onload = () => {
      if ( request.status === 201 ){
        console.log("login successful!");
        console.log(request.responseText)
        // this.setState({userI})
        return true
      } else {
        console.log("Failed login : ", request.status)
        console.log(request.responseText);
        return false
      }
    }
    let dataToSend = {}
    dataToSend["email"] = email
    dataToSend["password"] = password
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataToSend));
    request.send(JSON.stringify(dataToSend))
  }
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Try without the JSON.stringify

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: without JSON.stringify, it comes through as:

{ 'object Object': '' }

Comment: Why are you sending JSON when you said you're sending URL-encoded in the `Content-type` header?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content-type` header says you're sending URL-encoded data, not JSON. So it should be:

```
dataToSend = `email=${encodeURIComponent(email)}&password=${encodeURIComponent(password)}`;
request.send(dataToSend);
```

Or you should change the content type:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Comment: URL encoded returned the same `object Object` problem unfortunately

Comment: is setRequestHeader required?

Comment: Only if you want something different from the default.

Comment: `object Object` is what you get when you try to use an object where a string is expected. You should be accessing the properties, `obj.email` and `obj.password`